# How can I save data json in database using cast on the laravel?

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5.6

I use Laravel 5.6.

My model like this:

```php
class Product extends CachedModel {
    protected  $fillable = ['...','photo_list',];

    protected $casts = [
        'photo_list' => 'array'
    ];

    public function scopeOfUpdate($query, $photoList) {
        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($photoList); echo '</pre>'; die();
        return $query->where('id', 1)->update(['photo_list' => $photoList]);
    }
}
```

The result of:

```php
echo '<pre>';
print_r($photoList);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

Is like this:

```php
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => tQQ8lGsIxHmfqH8HVGWz9cjwFFNvgEXgaUPnOsNO.png
)
```

If the code executed, there exist error like this:

> Array to string conversion (SQL: update `products` set `photo_list` =
>   1, ....

I follow this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting to save json data to database. But seems it does not works.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query scopes are not mean to update records.

Try like this in your controller instead:

```
$product = Product::find(1);

$product->photo_list = [1, 2, 3];

$product->save();
```